# Requirement of different reagents for bromination of different substituted benzene rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, reactivity

Consider the bromination reactions of phenol and anisole. We know that the former can be brominated by aqueous bromine, while the latter requires the catalyst $\ce{FeBr3}$ instead.

Our teacher said that $\ce{-OH}$ is a stronger ring activator. So, polarization of bromine takes place easily and, hence, phenol doesn’t require a Lewis acid for bromination.

But, [this related question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/why-is-a-hydroxyl-group-more-activating-than-a-methoxy-group-in-electrophilic-ar) had the conclusion that both anisole and phenol are practically equally activating. So, does aqueous bromine react with anisole too? If not, why is there a difference in the reagents? If yes, do we get 2,4,6-tribromomethoxybenzene?

We have a similar case with chlorobenzene also. Difference in electronegativity between $\ce{C-O}$ is more than that in $\ce{C-Cl}$. So, chlorine must be able to give one of its lone pairs and activate the ring more readily than oxygen. But even bromination of chlorobenze requires a Lewis acid. Why is this so?

---

**PS:** I checked [this similar question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33046/why-do-we-need-to-add-febr3-for-bromination-of-anisole-but-not-for-bromination) on our site but a proper reason wasn’t stated to my question.

Comment: $\ce{-OH}$ is a better activator than $\ce{-OCH3}$ see this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/why-is-a-hydroxyl-group-more-activating-than-a-methoxy-group-in-electrophilic-ar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a hydroxyl group more activating than a methoxy group in electrophilic aromatic substitution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/why-is-a-hydroxyl-group-more-activating-than-a-methoxy-group-in-electrophilic-ar)

Comment: So even anisole undergoes the same reaction?

Comment: The accepted answer says they both are practically equally reactive.

Comment: It might be true that $\ce{-OH}$ and $\ce{-OCH3}$ are about equally activating. But phenol in water is partially _deprotonated_, and $\ce{-O^-}$ is a great deal stronger than both.

Comment: Interesting! And phenoxide ion is stabilised by resonance. Thats a good reason. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I was taught that phenoxide ion is only stable in basic medium. Can it also form and remain stable in neutral medium?

Comment: @GaurangTandon "Stable" is a word that means nothing, so you may just as well stop using it. True, to deprotonate **all** phenol molecules we'd have to go into much higher pH. With neutral solution, at any given moment only a tiny portion of them is deprotonated. This is also the portion that reacts. Then they exchange protons, and we go on to brominate another portion. Then another.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Alright, makes sense. Still, your comment makes me feel that aqueous bromination of phenol will be a slow process. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Not particularly. See, the portions may be tiny, but they exchange really fast, and each portion brominates pretty fast, too.

Comment: Phenol is easily brominated by bromine in water. The reaction hereby proceeds to 2,4,4,6-tetrabromocyclohexadienone. The reason for this is, as Ivan already explained, the presence of phenolate anions. The product can be reduced to 2,4,6-tribromophenole by sodiumhydrogensulphite.